# How to make Material ExposedDropdownMenu with a multiline dropdown item layout?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, material-design

I tried to implement Material ExposedDropdownMenu. The names of the elements are very long, and I need to show them completely, but the drop-down list shows only one line, and the name is truncated. How can I fix it?

I tried different styles of the TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView. `singleLine=true`, `lines=4` and `maxLines=4` in the dropdown item layout also do not help.

ExposedDropdownMenu

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/trotuar_plity_spinner"
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/trotuar_plity_subtitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:hint="Плиты">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/trotuar_plity_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Dropdown item layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:lines="4"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"/>
```

Dropdown init:

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    AutoCompleteTextView spinnerDropdown = requireView().findViewById(R.id.tv_dropdown);
    mViewModel.getItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (items -> {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, items);
//            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Ever figured this out...?

Comment: I suppose it's possible to override the style of the dropdowns or replace their layouts with custom ones, but since then I have not dealt with the problem. Maybe I'll try later.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying several things with custom adapters I found 1 way which is quite hacky but it works:

I haven't got around to cleaning this up but the trick was to post a forced disable on horizontal scrolling in `getView()`.

```
class CustomArrayAdapter(context: Context,
    @LayoutRes private val layoutResource: Int,
    @IdRes private val textViewResourceId: Int = 0) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layoutResource) {


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = createViewFromResource(convertView, parent, layoutResource)

        view.post {
            view.setHorizontallyScrolling(false)
        }

        return bindData(getItem(position)!!, view)
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = createViewFromResource(convertView, parent, R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item)

        return bindData(getItem(position)!!, view)
    }

    private fun createViewFromResource(convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup, layoutResource: Int): TextView {
        val context = parent.context
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false)
        return try {
            if (textViewResourceId == 0) view as TextView
            else {
                view.findViewById(textViewResourceId) ?:
                throw RuntimeException("Failed to find view with ID " +
                    "${context.resources.getResourceName(textViewResourceId)} in item layout")
            }
        } catch (ex: ClassCastException){
            Log.e("CustomArrayAdapter", "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView")
            throw IllegalStateException(
                "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView", ex)
        }
    }

    private fun bindData(value: String, view: TextView): TextView {
        view.text = value
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be a cleaner way to disable this, maybe through override of styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try the layout that comes as defualt in the SDK with spinners:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

The key is to use: `ellipsize "marquee"` it will show & give you a horizontal scrollable for your full text.